# Using OpenXML SDK with .Net framework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, openxml, openxml-sdk

We are building our application in .Net framework 4.0 and need to have reference to OpenXML v2.0 sdk for generating word documents.  OpenXML needs .Net 3.5 Sp1 (even though we have .net 4.0 installed on the system, it insists on installing .net 3.5 sp1), so if I reference OpenXML dlls in my application does that mean I cannot build my application targeting .Net framework 4.0 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am currently using the Open XML SDK 2.0 dll's while targeting .NET 4.0 and haven't had any issues at all.  It probably just needs at least .NET 3.5 sp1 or later to run, so if you can get the dll's without installing .NET 3.5 sp1 you should be fine.